# How to remove trailing slash adding in pagination urls

Tags: magento2.3, htaccess, rules, condition

I have added code in my htaccess to add trailing slash in my Magento 2.3.2 website URLs.

I want to exclude the pagination pages including questions to add a trailing slash.

For example - I have URL https://example.com/blog?p=2 which is redirecting to https://example.com/blog/?p=2.

I want to exclude these pages with "blog?p" to add a trailing slash.

Please provide a solution.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with .htaccess using 'rewrite condition'

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] #
```